# Html Sub-Accordions don't open

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I created a sub-accordion to my site, but when I click on it, the text doesn't appear.

I tried to remove the other accordions and modify the js code but the problem remains.

I think that there's a problem in the JavaScript code because the main accordion is working.

I found the tutorial on w3schools. Here is the link: https://w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

```js
var acc = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion,.subaccordion');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: .15rem;
  background-color:#fafafa;
}

.subaccordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: .15rem;
  background-color:#fafafa;
}


.active, .accordion:hover, .subaccordion:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.accordion:after, .subaccordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: poppins;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.title {
  font-family: Poppins;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Accordions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">Accordions Test</h1>
    <button class="accordion">Accordion 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <button class="subaccordion">Subaccordion 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Accordion 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: To keep things simple, you might want to use the `<details>/<summary>` elements instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Nesting works very easily with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue come from maxHeight is still affected to parent node when you click on sub accordion

an idea can be to wait the end of transition on panel to recalculate maxHeight on parent

```
panel.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    panel.parentNode.style.maxHeight = panel.parentNode.scrollHeight + "px";
});
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.accordion, .subaccordion')].forEach(acc => {
  acc.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});

[...document.querySelectorAll('.panel')].forEach(panel => {
  panel.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    panel.parentNode.style.maxHeight = panel.parentNode.scrollHeight + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: .15rem;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.subaccordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-top: .15rem;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover,
.subaccordion:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.accordion:after,
.subaccordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: poppins;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.title {
  font-family: Poppins;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Accordions Test</h1>
<button class="accordion">Accordion 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="subaccordion">Subaccordion 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Accordion 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
```